# Angular 11 file upload formdata to asp.net core api is empty

Tags: xml, angular11

I am trying to upload file from Angular 11 application using HttpClient post to asp.net core api. But the formdata is always empty.The Request.HasFormContentType is always false. Not sure how to fix this.

Angular:

```
public upload(formData: any): Observable<boolean> {
    this.uploadStarted.next();
    console.log(formData);
    return this.apiService.post<FormData, boolean>('url', formData, { content: formData });
}
```

asp.net core 3.1 webapi:

```
[HttpPost("validate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Validate()
    {
        if (!Request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Can anyone please help me with this? I tried to set the 'multipart/form-data' content type as well. But didnt worked.

Comment: Check it in ```Request.Form.Files```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your files in `Request.Form.Files`

```
[HttpPost("validate")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Validate()
    {
        if (Request.Form.Files.Length == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```